# Visual Studio Team Services Rest API unauthorized_client error

Tags: javascript, azure-devops

I am developing an JavaScript app to create work items in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). But While authenticating I am getting the below error.

> {"Error":"unauthorized_client","ErrorDescription":null}

I don't want to write any C# code so I am doing it all on html/javascript way.
I am getting the Auth_Code but access_token.

```
<form method="post" action="https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token?   redirect_uri=http://mycallbackurl" id="accesstoken" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="client_assertion_type" value="urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer" />
<input type="hidden" id="client_assertion" name="client_assertion" value="appSecret" />
<input type="hidden" name="grant_type" value="urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" />
<input type="hidden" id="assertion" name="assertion" value="auth_code" />
```

I am submitting the above form and In that I am getting this error.
I have even tried to do the same using $.ajax but the same result.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send a authorize users via client side code as per the FAQ on the Auth page of the API documention.

> Q: Can I use OAuth with my phone app?
>
> A: No. Right now, Visual Studio Team Services only support the web
>   server flow, so there's no supported way to implement OAuth for Visual
>   Studio Team Services from an app like a phone app, since there's no
>   way to securely store the app secret.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth

You have to do the OAuth handshake via server side code.

Comment: @Aaron I am getting the same error when I do this from server side in node.js using request package

Comment: Can you provide the raw HTTP requests you are sending? Maybe you are not setting up the requests correctly.

Comment: Does this mean it's not possible to make updates (e.g. to Work Items) in Ajax calls too? I've got all of the OAuth stuff working in C# for obtaining an Access Token for the user and querying Work Items and so on, and I've got a nice UI working with Ajax updates to VSTS using a Personal Access Token of my own. I'd like to use the user's OAuth Access Token for the Ajax calls instead of my PAT. Is that possible (and if so how? - I've been trying to figure it out for hours!).

Comment: Philip, typically, OAuth APIs will allow you to fetch an access token on behalf of the user via server side code. You could fetch the token for the user, then send that to your frontend, from which you could make authorized Ajax requests on behalf of the user. However, the ideal scenario for security would be to proxy user authenticated requests via the server side and keep the  user token in a database for reuse.